# How do I implment the web service methods of watershed/ustream?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, video-streaming

I'm supposed to use watershed to allow users to create and post their own videos on a website.

Watershed has it's own viewer for broadcasts and an application for recording broadcasts as well. It's all pretty well set up and easy to embed etc.

If you look at the watershed page (link at bottom of post) it says that you must implement all web service methods for the recording application to work, but it doesn't give any direction on how to implement them.

Am I supposed to do this with javascript? actionscript? how does one go about implementing these "web service methods" I tried to do it with actionscript but I'm not really sure how to put actionscript into my page and what I had typed did not work. Any points in the right direction on what to use or even what some of this stuff means would be greatly appreciated.

https://watershed.ustream.tv/support/advanced_customization/using_web_services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find [this project](https://github.com/MaherSaif/Ustream-Watershed-WebService) on github, which is extremely helpful. Put the two files from there on your server. After that go to the watershed site and log in. Under the brands tab, click on properties from the side bar and then advanced settings. Put the link to the `soap_service.php` on your server and it'll respond to the methods. You can edit the `soap_services.php` and make the methods do what you want. Hopefully this helps people out who are in the same situation.